# C# Converting image file to hex and hex to image

Tags: c#, image-processing, hex, filtering

I try send image from arduino with radio module and receive in my `c#` desktop application. 
Fisrtly, I convert any taken image to hex, then send that with radio module. The next step I save the hex to img.txt file.
Finally, I want to convert hext to image file, and show converted image on PictureBox. Which way or code I'd use?

1. I converted hex (which was sent with radio module) to image in online website, that worked.
2. Is there any other way? (ex: byte, int array, or anything)

I found these codes, but it didn't work

```
var str = new SoapHexBinary(File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\test.txt")).ToString();
var str2 = BitConverter.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\test.txt"));
```

I tested in my desktop app with this codes.
Converting image file to byte array:

```
 Image img = Image.FromFile(@"E:\1681010.png");
            byte[] arr;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                arr = ms.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\test.txt", arr);
```

Then, reading file and converting to image:

```
 byte[] pic = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\test.txt");
                MemoryStream buf = new MemoryStream(pic);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(buf, true);
                image.Save(@"E:\t.jpg");
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"E:\t.jpg";
```

Comment: Do you know what format the picture is sent in? "Hex" is just a byte array in string form. You should convert it back to binary form and write it to the file, but you need to name the file with the correct extension for Windows to recognize it (in some cases the information in the image header is enough, but not always).

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, I know the format. It will be .jpeg format.
Also I tested the converting image to byte array and saved it to text.txt file. Then I converted the txt file to image it worked. Just I need some codes to make project.

Comment: @RonBeyer here is codes
Converting image file byte array, the saving in .txt file:
`Image img = Image.FromFile(@"E:\1681010.jpeg");
            byte[] arr;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                arr = ms.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\test.txt", arr);
            MessageBox.Show("Converted");`

Comment: Please modify your question with additional code, it is extremely difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @RonBeyer I add some codes to my question